# How to enable cors spring boot jhipster

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, jhipster

I have an angular application which connects to my spring boot application which I generated with jhipster. When I send a post request I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/api/materials-add' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

1. I tried activating Cors in my Application.dev.yml and then start with dev Profile but it did not work.
2. I tried putting this method in my Configuration Class:

   ```
   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping("/api/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", 
        "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
   }
   ```

But still no success.

3.

```
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = jHipsterProperties.getCors();
        if (config.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !config.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/management/**", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("http://localhost:4200/**",config);
        }
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

This was a code which already existed I just added the last line with localhost:4200. But still no luck. Could someone help me or give me an advice what could I try next?

Intellij error:

```
2020-12-25 20:17:47.229  WARN 38287 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
2020-12-25 20:17:47.231  WARN 38287 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource]
```

But I am logged in authorization via my gateway and my gateway and my Microservice both register in the same registry, so I should be authorized is this error due to CORS?

I just read this part in my application.dev.yml:
CORS is disabled by default on microservices, as you should access them through a gateway.

In my gateway I already allowed cors via the application.dev.yml like this:

```
cors:
    allowed-origins: '*'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is that

allowed-origins: '*' &
allow-credentials: true

cannot be used together, as that would be dangerously insecure.

See here for more details
https://portswigger.net/web-security/cors/access-control-allow-origin

Remove allow-credentials or specify http://localhost:8081 etc in place of the allowed-origins wildcard